# Include Google Play Services jar as part of the project?

Tags: android, service, jar, google-play

Is it possible/recommended to include the Google Play Services jar file as part of your android project vs. including it as the dependent library?

This page http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html asks you to include the Google Play Services as part of the dependent library. But for simplification purpose, I was thinking of including the jar as part of the android project itself.

Anyone has done this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Library project contains string resources. They are not included in jar file. However if you copy XML file also it will be probably working fine.